# Stripe, webhooks and SCA European law checkout flow

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a website with Stripe payments, it's europe based so I'll have to deal with SCA 3D Secure auth, stripe docs recommend me to deal with payment fulfillment asynchronously instead of waiting for confirmCardPayment promise to resolve, to accomplish this you have to use webhooks.

From the docs:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
  payment_method: {
    card: card,
    billing_details: {
      name: 'Jenny Rosen'
    }
  },
  setup_future_usage: 'off_session'
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Show error to your customer
    console.log(result.error.message);
  } else {
    if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
      // Show a success message to your customer
      // There's a risk of the customer closing the window before callback execution
      // Set up a webhook or plugin to listen for the payment_intent.succeeded event
      // to save the card to a Customer

      // The PaymentMethod ID can be found on result.paymentIntent.payment_method
    }
  }
});
```

Notice the comment that says:

```
// There's a risk of the customer closing the window before callback execution
// Set up a webhook or plugin to listen for the payment_intent.succeeded event
```

Because of that warning I'm confused about how to deal with confirmCardPayment promise.

Should I just take the user to another page after I call confirmCardPayment from client and show the order in that new page with status: PENDING or PROCCESING.

Should I do this a few seconds after calling confirmCardPayment with a timer or check there is no error in callback, inside the else brackets of the promise callback and use location.href there to move user to see the order?

After that I would deal with order fulfillment in backend with webhooks (listen to payment_intent.succeded event, remove from stock, send order email and do remaining database operations)

If I do this would the SCA modal still show up? Stripe says Stripe.js deals with SCA and showing modal but if I redirect user to pending orde page with no stripe.js how would SCA modal action complete?

This is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When we confirm the card payment on the front, we basically close the payment modal, and show the "order" page or whatever page you have with the current status.

We are pushing server updates of status changes from the server to the client using Pusher, which enables us to update the client for user convenience.

If using pusher or another socket based solution is not possible, you could display it in a status "please wait" and poll for server update every X time.

There is no "right or wrong" here; it just depends on your setup and what your exact requirements are...

Comment: I know, but how where do you confirm the payment? when SCA modal is completed? after confirmCardPayment promise is received? can a user complete SCA outside the web?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  SCA is dealt with by Stripe.  They handle everything for you, including the 3DS verification.

Comment: SCA is done when they "agree" to setup the paymentIntent.  that's when Stripe (strongly) identifies the customer.  So when you get the webhook and you confirm the charge, the customer already actually agreed for you to capture the payment.
Depending on the flow, you won't be able to charge "more than" what you agreed for with the customer when you had him agree to the paymentIntent you created.